# 32-bit 4GB virtual cloud servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2

Does anyone know why AWS/EC2 and GoGrid don't allow 4GB memory cloud instances?

I want to set up a 32-bit Microsoft Windows Server 2003 cloud instance with 4GB but I can only get a maximum of 2GB. I can't go to 64-bit because the software I'm installing on my instance doesn't support it.

Does anyone know of any other virtual server providers that do allow this?

Cheers, Shane

Answer (score 1):

Check out [FlexiScale](http://www.flexiscale.com). They have both Windows 2003 and 2008 server images in both 32-bit and 64-bit editions.  When you set up a server, you are able to configure a specific amount of memory (in 0.5GB to 1GB increments) and the number of processors required.

I've just launched a 32-bit instance of Windows 2008 server on a machine with one processor and 4GB of RAM and it sees exactly 4GB physical, with 3.4GB free.

Comment: It reports that 4GB is physically installed, but it still can't use the full 4GB. Vista with SP1 behaves the same way, i.e. it reports the amount physically installed, whereas before SP1 it reported the total available to the OS.

Comment: True, being 32-bit you won't be able to make use of the full 4GB on any platform, but it gives the OP a bit more room than 2GB as he's forced to use 32-bit.  Selecting a 3GB instance is also an option and is slightly cheaper - perhaps this would give a similar usable amount.

Comment: Many 32-bit Server OSes can see more than 4GB assuming that PAE is enabled. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: PAE under Xen, especially in the domU, isn't particularly stable.  Honestly, though, just bug the vendor for a 64-bit version of their software.  It's not as though 64-bit OSes should be some sort of surprise these days...

Comment: Ah, good fact to know, I don't use Xen much, I'm deeply entrenched in VMWare products. The OP can't got x64 though, he said his app doesn't run on it.

Comment: I'll definitely check out FlexiScale, thanks for the heads-up.  Have you found their service any good, I haven't heard of them before.  Also, the 4GB limit minus the OS usage is fine, I don't need 4GB actual usable memory, and as for bugging the vendor for 64-bit, it's SAP ;) Somehow, I don't think they'll listen.

Comment: I just noticed the servers are UK based, which doesn't help me in Australia/US. Bummer.